# How to replace a matched text (match#2) in a line found after a match #1

Tags: unix, sed

I have to a find a solution to this problem: I need to replace text only if the second line has *`match #2`* and the previous line has *`match #1`*.

I'll explain... I have this text in a file:

```
ms.sapAB1_ASCS10     critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER AB1adm
ms.sapAB1_SCS11      critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
en.sapAB1_ASCS10     critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
en.sapAB1_SCS11      critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
ig.sapAB1_DVEBMGS20  critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/START_ASCS10_eati01
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/START_SCS11_eati01
icman                critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*ARGS pf=/usr/sap/AB1/SYS/profile/AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01
```

so, in my case, I need to replace *`match #2`* with `XX1_DVEBMGS20_eati01`, only when there's a *`match #1`* in the previous line.

So, for:
*`match #2`* = `AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01` and *`match #1`* = `sapstartsrv`

The result would have to be:

```
ms.sapAB1_ASCS10     critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER AB1adm
ms.sapAB1_SCS11      critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
en.sapAB1_ASCS10     critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
en.sapAB1_SCS11      critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
ig.sapAB1_DVEBMGS20  critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/XX1_DVEBMGS20_eati01
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/START_ASCS10_eati01
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/START_SCS11_eati01
icman                critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*ARGS pf=/usr/sap/AB1/SYS/profile/AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01
```

(The line after `icman` should NOT change, although it also had the *`match #2`*)

I need to do this using sed, ideally, and it needs to work on any Unix machine (not just Linux).

so far, I've tried this:

```
sed -e "s/AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01/XX1_DVEBMGS20_eati01/" ./teste.cfg > ./teste_new2.cfg
```

--> but it changed every occurence of `AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01`

```
sed -e "/sapstartsrv/{n;p;}" -e "s/AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01/XX1_DVEBMGS20_eati01/" ./teste.cfg > ./teste_new2.cfg
```

--> this was the result:

```
ms.sapAB1_ASCS10     critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
ms.sapAB1_SCS11      critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
en.sapAB1_ASCS10     critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
en.sapAB1_SCS11      critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
ig.sapAB1_DVEBMGS20  critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*PUSER ab1adm
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01
*ARGS pf=/.*/XX1_DVEBMGS20_eati01                                       
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/START_ASCS10_eati01
*ARGS pf=/.*/START_ASCS10_eati01                                        
sapstartsrv          critical   1-      TT_SAP          0900-1700 1-5
*ARGS pf=/.*/START_SCS11_eati01
*ARGS pf=/.*/START_SCS11_eati01                                         
icman                critical   1-      TT_SAP          0000-2400 *
*ARGS pf=/usr/sap/AB1/SYS/profile/XX1_DVEBMGS20_eati01
```

Can someone help me find the solution?

thanks
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e '/sapstartsrv/{' -e 'n;s/AB1_DVEBMGS20_eati01/XX1_DVEBMGS20_eati01/g}' file
```

Yours is quite close, the mistakes are the `p` and the quotes.
`n` will print `hold space`, so no need to use `p`.
The replace needs to be inside the condition block.
For compatibility, `sed` needs start new `-e` block whenever started `{` and closed `}`.